# What are the messages communicated by Pope Francis' advice of 7th January to parents?

Tags: catholicism, worship, pope-francis

In a news item of National Catholic Register titled 'Pope Francis baptizes babies in the Sistine Chapel on January 7, 2024. Vatican Media ' the following is found :

> The Pope told parents to let their babies cry during the Mass, joking that once one baby cries then “the concert will begin.”.

It is natural for babies to follow suit if one baby in a group cries aloud- whatever be the reasons. The parents of the baby which starts crying, mostly takes the child outside the church, so that the celebrant and faithful are not distracted. There have also been Parish Priests reprimanding the parents whose babies cry during the service. But the message of Pope Francis calls for a paradigm shift. Perhaps he means that the service can run uninterrupted even if there is a  'concert crying' of babies; and that the celebrant as well as the faithful should take it cool. My question is: What are the messages communicated to the clergy and the laity by Pope Francis' advice of 7th January to parents ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a paradigm shift to me. We have lots of young families with babies, and the babies will cry and babble throughout Mass. Some parents will take the kids out if they are really misbehaving, but most of the time they aren't so bad. No one has ever reprimanded parents at my parish to my knowledge because their child made noise during Mass.